# POSTing two pieces of small data to an MVC3 site with HttpWebRequest

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, post, httpwebrequest

I need to `POST` a `Guid` and an `int` value onto an MVC3 site.

What is the simplest way to do it?

I am using an `HttpWebRequest` instance on a client side.
So far I am thinking to just `POST` to an action-mapped URL, and include both data units as JSON data.

How do I process such case in an MVC3 action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to allow a user to submit data (I couldn't quite tell if this is what you meant from your question - if not, please clarify), you can do something like this:

```
@Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { guid = "your-guid-value" , myInt = 4 }) { 
  @* Your Form - Set those values here. *@ 
}
```

Your Controller method would be:

```
public ActionResult ActionName(string guid, int myInt) { 
  /* Do whatever you need with the data and return the appropriate view */
}
```

Of course, the other alternative, depending on your needs, is create a [strongly-typed view](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/10/13/asp-net-mvc-3-beta-strongly-typed-views-in-razor.aspx) and use an object (rather than a string and an int value) to handle the data.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, a POSTing side is using an HttpWebRequest class instance. I am not doing web-page -> controller data manipulation. A .net application is posting data, and I need a proper way of parsing it in an MVC3 action method.

Comment: I can use a custom model binder and just parse the JSON data manually, but I think MVC3 has a more generic aproach to simply posting data to a controller, other then the URI mappings.